# Hive Query doesn`t allow >= in the where clause

Tags: hive, subquery, hiveql

I have a Hive query which returns the `max_date` (single row,single column) which is to be used against master table for filtering data. I use a temp table to generate the logic for `max_date`

```
create temporary table umt (processdate date);
insert into umt ( 
select 
code for max_date from a_table 
where processname = 'a_process'
);
```

I want to use this max_date in my master_table query.
If I use a hardcode date to filter the master_table I get the results in 1-2 mins

`select data from master_table where process_date >= '2020-09-01';`   1-2 mins

however If I do a join it takes more than 15 mins. The master_table is partitioned on process_date column
`select data from master_table inner join umt on process_date >= umt._max_date;` ~ 15 mins

Is there any way to improve the performance or any way to substitute the max_date in the query to avoid join?